# Lumen, authentication attempt always returns false (jwt or auth)

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, jwt, lumen

I made a small API with the php lumen framework.

Now I'm integrating a jwt authentication (following this tuto http://laravelista.com/json-web-token-authentication-for-lumen/) for my application but as I attempt to login, it always returns false...

It doesn't seem to be a problem with `jwt` directly because the token generation works but only the login doesn't work. As I saw, `jwt` use the `Lumen Auth::` to login, so to be sure I tried to login with `Auth::attempt()` directly instead of `JWTAuth::attempt`, but the result is `false` too...
Here is my code:

```
try
{
   $validation = $this->validate($request, [
      'email'    => 'required|email',
      'password' => 'required'
   ]);

   $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

   $isAuthenticated = Auth::attempt($credentials) || JWTAuth::attempt($credentials);

   $user = User::first();
   $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);

   $result = [
     'isAuthenticated' => $isAuthenticated,
     'token' => $token
   ];
 // ... catch exceptions + return $result or errors from exceptions
```

I made some search to correct the common mistakes with this kind of problems, and I already checked that:

- I have a table named `users`
- in which I have a `password` column and an `email` column (full lowercase names)
- db `password` column is varchar(140)
- and tried to create and login a user like this:

  ```
  $user = new User;
  $user->email = 'example@domain.com';
  $user->password = Hash::make('passwordExample');
  $user->save();
  //And login with it:
  $userData = array(
    'email' => 'example@domain.com',
    'password' => 'passwordExample');            
  return (string) Auth::attempt($userData));
  ```

  - my auth config contains :

  'driver' => env('AUTH_DRIVER', 'eloquent'),
  'model' => env('AUTH_MODEL', 'App\Models\User'),
  'table' => env('AUTH_TABLE', 'users'),

  - my `App\Models\User` model `implements Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` and use `Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable`

But no changes... I always get a 'false' !
What can be the problem?

Here are the framework version I use (from composer.json)

```
    "laravel/lumen-framework": "5.1.*",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "~1.0",
    "doctrine/dbal": "~2.3",
    "illuminate/mail": "^5.1",
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "^0.5.6",
    "basicit/lumen-vendor-publish": "^1.0",
    "illuminate/support": "5.1.25",
    "illuminate/routing": "5.1.25"
```

Note : I also notice that for the same password hashed twice, the result is not the same. As I read, it's normal and the Auth knows how to check the hashed stored password. But I don't get it... How does he check the password if the hashed result is never the same? It stores a salt for each hash?

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/understanding-passwords -> this doesn't solve my problem but has answered my note question

Comment: Are the config variables also being set in your `.env` file? If so they will overwrite the ones in the `/config` folder.

Comment: @Jeemusu thanks for your reply. The `.env` has the same values as the `/config`. I tried to remove the entries to let only the values from the `auth config` but it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well... Took me a while but I figured out how to login properly...

If I set the password without hashing it :

```
$user = User::select('id', 'email')
  ->where('email', $email)
  ->first();
$user->password = $newPassword;
$user->save();
```

and I look in the db what was inserted, the password is stored encrypted...

Then if I try to login with :

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'email'    => 'required|email|max:255',
    'password' => 'required'
]);
$credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
if ( $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials) )
...
```

it works properly.

So my problem was that I hashed twice the password before inserting it.

But I don't really understand why it's automatically hashed because as I saw in the doc, I have to do it explicitely. So if anyone can give me the reason, I would be very intersted to know it.

Anyway, I should have used `Hash::needsRehash($hashed)` directly...

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Also helped to me!

Comment: `Auth::attempt(['email' => 'user@domain.com', 'password' => '123456']);` return false